# COUNT(*) function not working in SELECT query

Tags: joomla-2.5, mysql, jdatabase

I wrote a simple SQL statement that counts the number of category IDs in a table. Problem is, its returning `NULL`.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('category_id','COUNT(*)')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__eb_event_categories'))
      ->group($db->quoteName('category_id'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList(); 
var_dump($results);
```

When I remove `COUNT(*)` the select statement is working normally. What did I write incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `quoteName` from your `select` clause, so it will then look like this:

```
$query->select(array('category_id','COUNT(*)'));
```

Using `$db->quoteName()` on an array will wrap all array values in backticks when the query is rendered.

`category_id` is okay to wrap in backticks via `$db->quoteName()` because it is a column name.

`COUNT(*)` is a MySQL function. It loses its meaning if wrapped in backticks.

Your original query was seeking a column called `COUNT(*)` -- which of course isn't correct (or available).

Comment: So that's is correct : $query->select((array($db->quoteName('category_id'),'COUNT(*)')); ??